# How to open Whatsapp with a specific phone number from a Xamarin Forms iOS app?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, whatsapp

I need to know how can I open WhatsApp from my app to a specific number. For Android, the following is working fine but I don't know if it works with iOS. Here is my code for Android:

```
try
{
    Device.OpenUri(new Uri("whatsapp://send?phone=+678115361041"));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    await DisplayAlert("Not Installed", "Whatsapp Not Installed", "ok");
    await DisplayAlert("", ex.Message, "ok");
}
```

Comment: Tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45765458/613087

Comment: Use `UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new Uri("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=phoneNum"));`, there are several duplicate iusses in stack overflow.

Comment: UIApplication what is reference for that?

Comment: @waqaswaqas `UIKit` is reference for `UIApplication` in `Xamarin.iOS` project.